# Still having problem with JQUERY autocomplete

Tags: jquery, validation, autocomplete

Ok here is my code. I am trying to get it to where if the person doesnt select an option off the autocomplete and just types it in manually that it pops up a response asking them if they are sure that is a proper job number. The validate function does not work.

```
$( document ).ready(

    function()
    {
        $("#shipping").validate({
            rules: {
            projectnum: {
            required: true,
            remote: "job_validate.php"
                         }
                    }
            });
        $( '#shipping' ).submit(
            function()
            {
                    var pattern = new RegExp('[P|O|\.]*\\s?B(ox)?.*\\d+', 'i');
                    var required_fields = new Array(
                        'name',
                        'service',
                        'company',
                        'contact',
                        'street',
                        'city',
                        'state',
                        'zip',
                        'projectnum'
                    );


                        for( j in required_fields )
                        {

                            var theRequiredField = required_fields[j]
                            var inputField = $( '[name="' + theRequiredField + '"]' )

                            if( inputField.val() == '' )
                            {                                   
                                alert( "The '" + theRequiredField + "' field is required." );
                                inputField.focus();
                                return false;

                            } 
                            if( inputField.val().match(pattern))
                            {                                   
                                alert( "PO Boxes are not allowed." );
                                inputField.focus();
                                return false;

                            }


                        } 


        } // function

            ) // submit

        $( '[name="projectnum"]' ).autocomplete({
            source: "job_validate.php",
            minLength: 3

        });



    }

);
```

Comment: `$("#shipping").validate...` assigns the following function to the validate event of the "#shipping" control, how are you invoking validate? _please add the html for the '#shipping' control._

Comment: I guess that is where I am getting confused. The answers I have gotten in the past have been this validate function but with my other functions I am a little unsure where it should go.

Comment: We still need to see some of the HTML. is `<input id="shipping"... `a button (type submit) or a textbox (the content of which can be 'validated')? or some thing else?  My guess is that what you want to do is assign the validate function to a text input of some sort and invoke the validate function on the button submit. We need more from you to get you the results you want.

Comment: <input type="text" size="15" name="projectnum" id="projectnum" value="<?= htmlspecialchars( $shippingform -> proj_num ) ?>" />

Answer (score 0):

@Mike, what you provided is a control with an **ID** of "projectnum" rather than "shipping". My guess (and I don't mean to be unkind) is that you need to start with the "getting started" demos at [JQUERY Website](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

The code you offer originally:

```
$( document ).ready(

    function()
    {
        $("#shipping").validate({
```

narrates as "When the document is ready call the 'validate' function of the control with an ID of "shipping" with '(these parameters)'  ... which is why I have been asking to see *that control* .

In jquery parlance the `$("#shipping")` is called a *selector*. It selects all of the controls on the page that have an ID (that is what the `#` sign means) of "shipping". Because it is an ID selector, there should only be ONE. If you wanted "all of the controls with a class of "shipping" you would use the selector `$(".shipping")`

JQuery is a great extension of javascript and will eventually be a great tool for you to use. But I believe you need to take a step back and learn the basics and then re-address your question.

**note to others** *please do not either vote this up or down. It is not really an answer to @Mike's question, but I needed the extra space that the "answer box" afforded to give a full commentary*

Comment: Ok and no worries still kind of new to Jquery and that is what I was wondering and that is probably the reason it isnt working properly. The #shipping is the selector for my form.
<form method="post" action="shippingform/printingform.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="shipping">
So that is why I have it selected to validate all of the other input boxes on the page. I am just trying to figure out how to validate if the autocomplete was selected or if they just typed in the info.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. (_I don't typically name my forms (well, beyond 'form1', so I didn't even think about that possibility_) but still the form DOM does not have a native "validate" function to call. Work your way through the How jquery works and then rethink what you are trying to accomplish and much of what you are asking will come clear.